# Powershell - Write filename into same file

Tags: powershell

I have a lot of .csv Files and I want to write the filename into the same file, at the end of the last position.

For example in C:\CSV I have:

- P0_0050569F52981EE39CEF8C857147E850.csv
- P0_0050569F52981EE39CEF8D4825092850.csv
- P0_0050569F52981EE39CEF8EE13B954850.csv

...*and another thousand more of these files*

In every one of this files I have some content:

- P0_0050569F52981EE39CEF8C857147E850.csv = 365013;253;9001

I want to transform this: `365013;253;9001` to this:

- 365013;253;9001;
- P0_0050569F52981EE39CEF8C857147E850.csv

I cannot find the error...

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.csv" -Path "C:\CSV" -Recurse | % {

#Open file
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $_.FullName

#Ignore first line
$reader.ReadLine() | out-null

#Get name
$filename = $filename

#Write  
Add-Content ";" $filename

#Close stream
$reader.Close()

}
```

Comment: Did you mean $filename = $_.Fullname instead of $filename = $filename

Comment: MickyB, I think $_.name would be more accurate to what the request is since $_.fullname contains the full path to the file, directories included. In any case, your answer or mine is probably close enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MickyB's option should work. Here's another way to do it:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.csv" -Path "C:\CSV" -Recurse | foreach {$contents = get-content $_.fullname; $contents +=";"+"`r`n"+$_.name; Set-Content $_.fullname -Value $contents }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will happen the filename at the end of each CSV.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.csv" -Path "C:\CSV" -Recurse | % {

    (";"+"`r`n"+$_.name) | Out-File -FilePath $_.fullname -Append
}
```